# Перевод типа string в float Python

Tags: python, строки, типы-данных, float

Есть переменная, которая записывает в себя результат некой формулы:

```
result=float(cmb1.get()*10+cmb2.get()+cmb3.get()*10+cmb4.get()*10)
```

Из нескольких ComboBox подаются значения не целые числа.
При запуске программы выдаётся ошибка:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:'38.738.738.738.738.738.738.738.738.738.7100.1111111111111111111111'
```

Что я делаю не так?

Задача:
Есть 4 ComboBox'а. На них выбираются числа. Например: 38.7, 100.11, 1, 1 (для каждого ComboBox'а соответственно).
При нажатии кнопки эти числа должны считаться в вышеуказанную формулу и посчитать результат. Желательно результат округлить до целого (пока сам не сделал из-за ошибки)

Comment: Ну, `38.738.738.738.738.738.738.738.738.738.7100.1111111111111111111111` действительно не вещественное число. Укажите в вопросе (кнопка `править`) суть задачи, входные данные и ожидаемый результат

Comment: `float(cmb1.get())` и т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам нужно посчитать сумму значений, вам нужно каждое значение отдельно перевести в `float`:

```
result = float(cmb1.get())*10 + float(cmb2.get()) + float(cmb3.get())*10 + float(cmb4.get())*10
```

Это связано с тем, что для строк оператор `+` означает конкатенацию (склеивание), а не арифметическое сложение, равно как и оператор `*` является оператором мультипликации, а не арифметического умножения:

```
2 + 2 == 4
'2' + '2' == '22'

2 * 3 == 6
'2' * 3 == '222'
```

Comment: @AlexeyDidorenko, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)